# ASP.NET Chrome Reloading Page Many Times

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, encoding, query-string, reload

I have pages in ASP.NET (webforms) which accept query string parameters.

Whenever a date parameter is passed without encoding, Chrome is sort of reloading the page many times. To the user it is invisible, it appears to load normally only once. But when in debug mode, the page life cycle (such as the Page_Load sub) is called multiple times (11 times in one particular case).

Then I put the date encoded and it works just fine.

It only happens in Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera work normally.

Thank you!
Celso

Comment: Share the code and an example which can be tried to replicate the behavior.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know if anyone knows why the behavior I described is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As far as code goes, all that is different is the fact that the query string goes:
calendario.aspx?inicio=01/07/2013&fim=31/07/2013
When it comes like this it reloads the page 11 times.
Then I put it encoded:
calendario.aspx?inicio=01%2f07%2f2013&fim=31%2f07%2f2013
This way it works fine, loading the page only once.